# How to send a packet from tcp server to client use nodemcu(ESP8266) in arduino IDE?

Tags: tcp, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

In this code I wrote that the server send again what it received from client:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>

WiFiServer server(8080);
WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
  initHardware();
  setupWiFi();
  server.begin();
}
void loop() 
{
    if (!client.connected()) {
        // try to connect to a new client
        client = server.available();
    } else {
    // read data from the connected client
        if (client.available() > 0) {
          char inChar= client.read();
          String in=(String) inChar;

            Serial.print(in);           
            server.write(inChar);
        }
    }

}
void setupWiFi()
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.softAP("esp", "123456789");
//  WiFi.softAP("RControl", WiFiAPPSK);
}

void initHardware()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

Now it receive what I send from my PC, but it doesn't send anything to me.
Why? What is wrong here?

Comment: You might try `client.print` instead of `server.write`. Is there more code?

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/example-sketch-ap-web-server)

Comment: It works. Thank you so much

Comment: I change server.write to client.print and it works...